# Is "anecdotally" a proper adverb?

Tags: adverbs, is-it-a-word, syntactic-analysis

And if yes, is it common or rather odd?

Example sentence:

> Anecdotally, we do see instances of customers buying both our products
>   at the same store.

The Chrome spellchecker doesn't seem to know it, by the way:

[image: A screen capture showing the word "Anecdotally" underlined with a squiggly red line.]

Comment: Spellchecker is no substitute for a dictionary. Try looking in a dictionary. The word is common.

Comment: I did and found it in *some* dictionaries, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it's common in everyday language. Spellchecker is also not the only reason I'm asking, it also looks/sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: How can you **see** something anecdotally? If you mean you hear stories, you're not seeing but hearing; and you're not even hearing the event, you're hearing **rumors** of the event. Probly it's a bad choice of adverb in the first place; just because it's an adverb doesn't mean it lacks complex meaning and usage. In science, _anecdotal evidence_ means 'no real evidence'; it's a guess, at best, and a serious putdown at worst.

Comment: What I meant to express with my example was something along the lines of: "We don't have any *data* on how many customers buy both our products at the same store. However, we do know from *anecdotes* that this does happen from time to time."

Comment: @John: OP's example doesn't sound "off" to me. I understand *we see [blah]* as pretty much equivalent to *[blah] occurs* in this context. It can thus be seen (?!) as an "assertion" that *[blah]* is true, so it's not unreasonable to "temper" that assertion with expressions like *anecdotally, it seems that, apparently, I think,* etc. Not *hard-and-fast* or *"scientific"*, obviously, but I'm guessing that's the whole *point* of the "hedge".

Comment: @JohnLawler It seems to me that one can readily exchange *Anecdotally* there with *As one (individual/isolated)  anecdote/example/instance of this*, and that that is the sense the writer intended.  My swap still applies to the entire sentence following it, so I believe it still counts as a disjunct; is that right?

Comment: @tchrist: If you say so. I don't care much what it's called, only how it works in the sentence.

Comment: @JohnLawler Good enough. The point is that it applies to the entire sentence, not to the verb or whatnot. I guess that is what you were saying from the start. Sorry.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought that's what I was saying too. Functionally, *anecdotally* qualifies the entirety of the assertion that follows, so it's *not* really acting as an adverbial modifier of ***see***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t know what you mean by “a proper adverb”.

### *On Dictionaries and Software*

If you are concerned that it may not be found in this or that dictionary, this means nothing, since derived forms that are generated by productive ***derivational morphology*** are never fully enumerated in any dictionary.  The absence of a word from a dictionary never proves anything about its validity as   a word.

The OED has an entry for the adjective *anecdotal* and another for the adverb *anecdotically*.  I would rather read *anecdotally* than *anecdotically*, as a matter of personal preference.

I think what you are seeing is simply a difference in how Chrome applies derivational morphology, or perhaps fails to do so, within its spellchecking algorithm.  Other browsers give different results.  So for example in Safari, *anecdotally* though absent from the OED triggers no red squiggles, but 
*anecdotically* in contrast does so, even though it is present in the OED.

I’m therefore guessing this is nothing but a **software issue**, not an actual English issue at all.

### *On Syntactic Analysis*

On the other hand, if your concern here is how to analyse it syntactically, then you need to understand that this is an example of a ***sentence adverb***, not an adverb of manner or an intensifier. That means that it applies not to a single verb, adjective, other adverb, or preposition, but rather to the entire sentence as a single syntactic constituent.

What’s happening here is that you have an ***adverbial adjunct***, which in fact is actually a type of [***disjunct***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_%28linguistics%29).

Here are similar examples of disjuncts from the cited Wikipedia article:

> - *Honestly*, I didn't do it. (Meaning "I'm honest when I say I didn't do it" rather than "I didn't do it in an honest way.")
> - *Fortunately for you*, I have it right here.
> - *In my opinion*, the green one is better.
> - *Frankly*, this whole paragraph needs work.
> - *Interestingly*, the comment made for a great topic of its own.
> - *Luckily*, the amount of sugar the recipe called for was in stock in the pantry.
> - *Clearly*, the mail did not come today due to it being a national holiday.
> - *Unfortunately*, by the time she reached the bus stop, the bus had already left.

The sentence adverb is clearly a grammatical structure to native speakers, which is about as close to “proper” as you are going to get.

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't have expected, based simply on my analysis of the word forms, that "adjunct" could be a subset of "disjunct". That's a question in itself.

Comment: @tchrist: You left out the controversial one – [hopefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopefully).