# Adverb for "multiple"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adverbs

Say that I have [a Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charizard_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) with 2 types: Fire and Flying. One could say this Pokémon has "multiple types." That is because the designer of this Pokémon "typed" it that way.

Is it correct to say the Pokémon was "multiply typed," where "multiply" is an adverb describing how it was typed? Is there a better and succinct way of describing this typing process?

Comment: That (multiply typed) seems fine to me.

Comment: Here are a few written references to things which [*are multiply **specified***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+multiply+specified%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). OP's use of ***typed*** is probably more "unusual" than ***multiply***, but they're just uncommon forms, not "errors".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if you accumulate your comments into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Jackson: Despite the fact that some people (including at least you and Mynamite) aren't familiar with adverbial/adjectival ***multiply***, I think the question is General Reference (both myself and Lunivore had no problem finding the relevant dictionary definitions).

Comment: @Jackson: Or maybe just more prepared to extrapolate from "normal, acceptable" usages to "less common, but still acceptable" ones. I doubt you'd have a problem with reading about [*a multiply connected](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+multiply+connected%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) [thing which has multiple connections]*. So I reckon part of the problem is just that the slightly unusual usage ***typed*** had already put you "out of your linguistic comfort zone".

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, you could use the word *multi-typed*. However, I imagine this might cause confusion in Pokemon, since [*multitype* is itself a specific Pokemon ability](http://pokemondb.net/ability/multitype). If this describes exactly what you're looking for then fantastic, but note that it comes with a set of rules that may not help to explain the multiple types outside of those rules.

*Multiply typed* is therefore fine. Note that the pronunciation of *multiply* in this instance is /-plē/ to rhyme with *ripply*, rather than /plī/ to rhyme with *fly*.

Comment: *Multiply* as an adverb doesn't seem to exist in the quick online search I've done.

Comment: @Mynamite It's right there in the top result for me (you need to click the "down" arrow to extend the result): https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=define%3A%20multiply

Comment: @Mynamite: I just Googled **define multiply adverb**. The first two references (Merriam-Webster and dictgionary.com) both have it. In MW it's defined as [***adverb** - in a multiple manner :  in several ways <multiply talented children>*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiply) (similar in dictionary.com).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hands up, I give in. Maybe it's a US thing? I don't think I've heard it used.

Comment: @Mynamite: I'm UK, same as you. Per my comment to the question itself, this use of ***multiply*** isn't very common. But I doubt it's particularly more or less likely on either side of the Atlantic.

Comment: @Mynamite I definitely have (and therefore had a heads-up on the pronunciation); based in England here.

Comment: @Mynamite Why should a dictionary need to carry a word produced by productive derivation for it to be a word? [That is never true.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/181551)  But just to keep you happy, you should know that the OED does indeed list *multiply* as  an adverb, with all the first citations provided ones written by various nineteenth-century Britons, no less!

Comment: @Lunivore Using standard notation (and citing the OED here), the adverb is pronounced `/ˈmʌltɪplɪ/`, while the verb is pronounced `/ˈmʌltɪplaɪ/` with an unreduced diphthong at the end. Some dictionaries indicate a non-reduced syllable that lacks primary stress by placing a secondary-stress mark in front of that syllable.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Pokemon is an (imaginary) creature with a personality, I would call this one *dual-natured*. Having "multiple types" is a more mathematical characteristic.

If you are discussing the Pokemon in a technical context, multiply-typed is just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You would do better to shorten it to **multi-typed**.

Your phrase could cause confusion in two ways. *Multiply* as a verb is pronounced to rhyme with lie (sorry, I don't know IPA). So the first reading is not with a short *y* sound eg rhyming with *hilly*.

*Typed* is also problematic because of confusion with keyboard typing, whereas as you mean *given*, or *accorded* a *type*.

**Addition:**
Given Lunivore's comment about Pokemon multitypes, how about **multi-granted**?

Comment: There's even more confusion than that if you use multi-typed with Pokemon, though: http://pokemondb.net/ability/multitype

Comment: @Lunivore Thanks, I'm not familiar with Pokemon types.

Comment: Me neither; I spotted it while searching for *multityped* to see if it could be used as one word, moments before you posted your answer.

Comment: Also the word *lie* in mathematics can be pronounced to rhyme with *hilly* too... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group

Comment: The English language is too much for me, I'm going to go live in a cave. Pronounced *cavvy*.

Comment: *Carvay*. As in, "Look out!" https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#q=define%3A%20cave