# Making adverbs from adjectives

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, is-it-a-word, is-it-a-rule

Is it possible to make an adverb out of any adjective? I am aware that not all word forms appear in all dictionaries and while I can find all word forms in some dictionaries, as a non-native speaker of English, I remain skeptical about the actual usage of these words.

Having said that, here are some examples, off the top of my head, of adverbs I (and, apparently, my spellchecker) have problems with:

> She spoke slurredly.
>
> He stared ruminantly.
>
> He grunted agitatedly.
>
> She exhaled relievedly.

I realize that the last one is particularly horrible, but these are only examples. Is it correct to write this? Would a native speaker of English ever say something like that?

This is related to my other question ([Use of adjective in place of an adverb to achieve same meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347250/use-of-adjective-in-place-of-an-adverb-to-achieve-same-meaning?noredirect=1#comment804622_347250)) and while the related post ([Is "anecdotally" a proper adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181546/is-anecdotally-a-proper-adverb)) has a partial answer, I would like a more definite and concrete answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking whether every adjective may be converted by inflection into an adverb, the answer is no. We say

> The program ran **long**.

not

> ***** The program ran **longly**.

The left side of a ship is its *port* side, but there's no adverbial for "in the left side manner". Certainly not *portly*.

The reverse is also true. The adverb *swimmingly* has no corresponding adjectival *swimming*.

> The contest went **swimmingly**

means something quite different from

> the **swimming** contest.

Past participles in general aren't adjectives, even though they modify nouns. Some like *slurred*, *agitated*, and *relieved* can be converted to adverbs by appending *-ly*. Some can't. Thus

> The **painted** bird depicts a feathered creature.

but not

> ***** The feathered creature was depicted **paintedly**.

Answer (score 1):

I like @deadrat's answer, so my contribution is more an exploration of *why* some adjectives don't have adverbial forms.

It might seem obvious to say that adjectives modify nouns and adverbs modify verbs, but therein lies the reason. Certain characteristics of *things* - for example, colour, cardinal number, location - make little sense when applied to *actions*, except in idiomatic or highly creative usage.

Examples of adjectives without an adverbial form include:

> - orange, indigo, purple, beige, olive;
> - five, thirteen, million (etc);
> - left, starboard, inside, top.

There are no doubt other categories of characteristics that describe things but not actions - in other words, have an adjectival but not an adverbial form.